# Missing past historical data that can be seen in Google Ads platform, but doesn't show upt Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I'm using BigQuery to store our Google Ads campaign performance information for our clients. To pull the data, I'm using a very simple query:

```sql
select *
from yl-adwords.ads.AdBasicStats_[our manager ID]
where ExternalCustomerId = [our media client's ID]
```

This query pulls back to 1/17/21. We took on this new client on 2/16/21, so we're able to get the past 30 days of data. However, the Google Ads account data goes back to 2019.

What's odd is for our other client accounts, when we get access using similar queries, we can pull back historical data with no issue. We're pulling others back to 2018, even though we started working with them ini 2020.

Do I need to schedule a backfill in BQ to get this new data? Or has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to set up a [backfill](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#backfilling) to get the historical data. One limitation is that you can only request 180 days per job, so you'll need to set up a couple if you want to go back to 2019.

The other, more severe constraint is that some [match tables are not able to be backfilled](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transformation#google_ads_match_tables). You can't run queries such as "show me the number of impressions for all campaigns that were active on such-and-such date" for backfilled dates.